# Apache, mod_php, and MINIT

Tags: php, apache, php-internals

When running PHP programs using `mod_php`, when does PHP call its extension's `MINIT` functions?  Does this happen

1. When the apache web server restarts?
2. Whenever apache spins up a new thread pool to handle PHP requests?
3. Whenever apache spins up a new individual thread?
4. Some other time?

Bonus questions: Is the `mod_php` source included as one of the [PHP SAPI handles](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/sapi)? (`apache2handler`?)

If so, is there a place in its source code I could have discovered the answer to my above question?